# Making an interval with point deleted complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am playing around with metric and topological spaces to get a better grasp of them, and I am wondering the following: is it possible to have a metric such that the set $[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$ is complete in the space $\mathbb{R}$ but the induced topology is still homeomorphic to $[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$ with the usual metric?

Comment: Your space is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty) \sqcup [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Simpler: $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,+\infty)$, per $1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the metric $d(x,y) = \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|$ on $X = [-1,0) \cup (0,1]$. It's easy to check that this is a metric.

The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is (by construction) an isometry between $(X,d)$ and $Y = (-\infty,1] \cup [1, +\infty)$ where the latter space has the usual Euclidean metric.

And $Y$ is complete (being closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ being complete in the Euclidean metric). And isometries preserve completeness, so $(X,d)$ is also complete.